# Sql Server query for Webpage

Tags: html, sql-server

I'm pretty new to web dev and need to pass arguments from the webpage and use them to query a mssql database. Unfortunately, I'm not very familiar with HTML and am in need of help/reference material. Could anyone help me?

Comment: google should help you better than SO. You'll have to learn about JSON, and HTTP Headers

Comment: This is entirely too broad. You need to narrow down your question by attempting something. Also, we don't even know what technology you are using for your application. dotnet, php etc...

Answer (score 1):

which programming language are you using?

In case of PHP you should look here: http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

In case of Java: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html